# Can you use the introspection function outside of iex?

Tags: bash, elixir

Can I use i() from outside of iex?  Are there other functions you can only access inside iex?

```
iex> i(3)
Term
  3
Data type
  Integer
Reference modules
  Integer
Implemented protocols
  IEx.Info, Inspect, List.Chars, String.Chars

bash> elixir -e "i(3)"
** (CompileError) nofile:1: undefined function i/1
(elixir 1.11.1) lib/code.ex:341: Code.eval_string_with_error_handling/3
```

Answer (score 5):

`i/1` is an import of [IEx.Helpers.i/1](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#i/1), so when it's available you can use the fully qualified name:

```
$ elixir -e 'IEx.Helpers.i(3)'
Term
  3
Data type
  Integer
Reference modules
  Integer
Implemented protocols
  IEx.Info, Inspect, List.Chars, String.Chars
```

If for some reason you want to use it within your own application, make sure to add `:iex` to `:extra_applications` in your `mix.exs`. Otherwise you'll get a warning about your application not depending directly on the `:iex` application (might just be newer versions of Elixir).

To answer your second question, I would imagine all of the helpers in [IEx.Helpers](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html) were intended to be be used only within IEx. You can see these in IEx by calling `h()`, which is imported from [IEx.Helpers.h/0](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#h/0), which prints the docs for [IEx.Helpers](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html).